# SQL Query returns a negative number but does not interpret it as a negative number but a positive number

Tags: sql, datediff, sql-view, intersystems-cache

When I run the query it is doing a DATEDIFF and getting a negative number as that is correct but its not interpreting the integer as a negative but as a positive number causing to use the wrong color to print as it should be red. What am I missing to make this work on negative numbers that should print red when the return datediff is <0.

```
Select
STRING(
case 
when datediff('hh',getdate(), ( CONVERT (CHAR(10),Table.end_date,121) ||' '|| Table.end_time ) ) > 7 
and "Table"."column" = '12' or "Table"."column" = 'JE'
then '</font><font color = green ><b>'
when datediff('hh',getdate(), ( CONVERT (CHAR(10),Table.end_date,121) ||' '|| Table.end_time ) ) > 2
and
datediff('hh',getdate(), ( CONVERT (CHAR(10),Table.end_date,121) ||' '|| Table.end_time ) ) <= 7
and "Table"."column" = '12' or "Table"."column" = 'JE'
then '</font><font color = yellow><b>'
when datediff('hh',getdate(), ( CONVERT (CHAR(10),Table.end_date,121) ||' '|| Table.end_time ) ) < 2
and "Table"."column" = '12' or "Table"."column" = 'JE'
then '</font><font color = red><b>'
else  '</font><font color = black >' end ,"Table"."column") AS "column"
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query uses several product specific functions.)

Comment: Are you SURE the results of `datediff` are negative? I'd suggest selecting just the result from `datediff`.

Comment: I'm using a Cache with a SQL view DB. Yes the datediff is returning a negative number.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. And don't forget to add a tag for the  dbms used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an [operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) problem.

Your conditions are variations of `diff and this or that`. `and` has a higher precedence than `or`. `one and two or three` really means...

```
(diff and this) or that.
```

in other words, if `that` is true it will always be true. In call your cases if `"Table"."column" = 'JE'` is true the whole statement will be true. That means you're always going to get green or black.

You probably mean

```
diff and (this or that)
```

And

```
(diff and diff) and (this or that)
```

---

Other notes.

- Turn `end_date` and `end_time` into proper date and time columns.
- Add an `end_at` timestamp column which already concatenates them.

Both of those will make queries simpler and faster; you don't have to convert a string, and comparisons like the above will be able to use an index on `end_at`.

- Don't quote table and column names unless you have to, it makes them case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you that did it. I added the parenthesis around the OR and it returned the correct color print. Thank you again.